# Resolve grid content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to center the whole content of the `grades_dashboard_box`. The layout itself is great but the content should be centered in the griddiv.

```css
.separation {
 width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);}
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
 height: 130px;
 width: auto;
 color: var(--text-color);
 transition: color 1s;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grade_info {
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.grades_dashboard_box>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grade_shortboard" class="separation">
                    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
                      <div>
                        <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_worst">14</h1>
                        <div class="grade_info">
                          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Schlechteste Durchschnittsnote</p>
                          <p id="grade_display_worst_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Biologie</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
                      <div>
                        <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_average">7</h1>
                        <div class="grade_info">
                          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Gesamte Durchschnittsnote</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
                      <div>
                        <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_best">10</h1>
                        <div class="grade_info">
                          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Beste Durchschnittsnote</p>
                          <p id="grade_display_best_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Swppl</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Here is an exampleimage:
CENTERED:
[image: centered]
NOT CENTERED:
[image: not_centered]
~filip

*EDIT:*
[image]
As you can see the font comes out of the box. And as I know this box is centered. So for the user, it does not look like the box is centered, because of the outcoming text. An additional way it would be to make the font smaller, but I don't want this. How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little to fit your need.
I added the **width:100px** on **strong text** instead of **.grades_dashboard_box** 
I also added **margin:auto;** in **.grades_dashboard_box**

```css
.separation {
 width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);}
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
 height: 130px;
 width: auto;
 color: var(--text-color);
 transition: color 1s;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grade_info {
 margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.grades_dashboard_box>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="grade_shortboard" class="separation">
                    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
                      <div>
                        <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_worst">14</h1>
                        <div class="grade_info">
                          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Schlechteste Durchschnittsnote</p>
                          <p id="grade_display_worst_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Biologie</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
                      <div>
                        <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_average">7</h1>
                        <div class="grade_info">
                          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Gesamte Durchschnittsnote</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
                      <div>
                        <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_best">10</h1>
                        <div class="grade_info">
                          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Beste Durchschnittsnote</p>
                          <p id="grade_display_best_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Swppl</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. It helped me a lot. At least. Can you please have a look at my Edit and try to help me again?

Comment: Great to hear that. So for the overflowing text all you need to do is add 
  "word-break: break-word;" style on your .grade_info class.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new parent element and give it `text-align:center;`

```css
.separation {
 width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);}
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
 height: 130px;
 width: auto;
 color: var(--text-color);
 transition: color 1s;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grade_info {
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.grades_dashboard_box>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
  width: 100px;
}

#newParent{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grade_shortboard" class="separation">
  <div id="newParent">
                    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
                      <div>
                        <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_worst">14</h1>
                        <div class="grade_info">
                          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Schlechteste Durchschnittsnote</p>
                          <p id="grade_display_worst_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Biologie</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
  </div>
```